# Verify Genuine Toyota Brakes

Tags: toyota, brakes, identification

Im selling items on eBay and a buyer complained that the brakes that I sent him aren't "Genuine Toyota" brakes. I'm almost certain they are genuine, but I'm not sure how to verify.

He says "The brake pads not genuine from dealer . It's only put it in genuine box ." Luckily, I got a picture of the brakes themselves.

So, ignoring the box, how can I tell that the brakes themselves are genuine Toyota?

Stamped on the brake is "Toyota 018 - AL NS368 FF"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The edge markings are correct. They could be faked, I suppose. I see no reason to call them non-genuine from that picture. Toyota uses brakes from several suppliers and they all look different. Some are black, some are green. They have been known to change suppliers for the same car.  So the ones coming off could be green and come from Sumitomo and the new ones supplied could be black from Akibono. High quality brakes pads have well made steel backing plates and low quality pads will tend to have poorly made backing plates with rough cut edges and inconsistent sizing. This is the most consistent way I know of to differentiate between low quality brakes and high quality brakes. It is much harder to tell quality by inspecting the brake material itself since it varies so much anyway.

Comment: The buyer probably noticed the pads he's taking off are different fro the pads going on, as you mentioned. Car manufacturers do change manufacturers, and the same car can be assembled at multiple plants, each with it's own supplier.

Comment: Yes, the ones in the image have the correct markings. You are probably being scammed out of your money.